# CD4017BE output pin question

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, cmos, cd4017

I am designing a circuit which uses a CMOS decade counter to activate and deactivate pairs of transistors in turns.The problem is:will the IC be damaged if the current of one of the outputs(activated) reaches another output(deactivated)?

Here is [the datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf)

Comment: Please try to link to actual direct PDFs, preferably manufacturers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "deactivate" an output of the CD4017B; outputs are always either very close to V<sub>DD</sub>, or they are very close to V<sub>SS</sub>. So yes, connecting a high output to a low output will create a near-short-circuit between V<sub>DD</sub> and V<sub>SS</sub>. Use an OR gate (or equivalent thereof) if you need to activate an input if either or both of two outputs are high.